# Is it possible to extract RDFa from html page using EasyRdf?

Tags: php, extract, rdf, rdfa, easyrdf

I'm trying to extract RDFa data from an html page using [EasyRDF](http://www.easyrdf.org/). But it doesn't seem to work. E.g., I've tried:

```
$work = new EasyRdf_Graph("http://example.com/");
$work->load();
echo $work;
$title = $work->primaryTopic();
echo "Title: ".$title->get('dc:title')."\n";
```

This is the error I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'EasyRdf_Http_Client only supports the 'http' and 'https' schemes.'

Comment: I don't see any error messages or unexpected output. What makes you think it's not working? "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself." example.com isn't real; you can't get data from it, so this doesn't count as valid code. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, **why they didn't work, and the expected results**."  What did you _expect_ this code to produce?  What did it actually produce?

Comment: Also, looking at http://www.easyrdf.org/, I don't see any mention of RDFa.  Do you have reason to believe that it would extract RDF from an RDFa document, and would do it automatically at that?  RDFa is a specification for _embedding_ RDF into XHTML.  Typically you might use an [RDFa distiller](http://www.w3.org/2012/pyRdfa/) to extract the RDF from an RDFa document, and then work with the RDF afterward.

Comment: EasyRdf 0.8 does support RDFa, but it's still in beta. you can use the converter at http://easyrdf-converter.aelius.com/ to test it out.

Also, what version of EasyRdf are you using with your code above?

Comment: I'm using version (0.7.2). I had reasons to believe RDFa would work automatically because I read it here: http://rdfa.info/dev/

«EasyRDF is a PHP library for extracting RDFa and working with RDF, in general.»

Comment: good point, I will fix the rdfa.info page to say that the version 0.8 should be used.